# Help needed for android quiz app

Tags: android

MY issue is that only the last option text is changing on the click of the Next button and the rest remain same. There is some problem with the loop i think.Can someone sort this out please.Thank you

Here's the db class:

```
package com.myapps.quiz;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.myapps.quiz/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "quiz";
    private static String Table_name="Quiz";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
    private SQLiteDatabase myData; 
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   



/**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{  
            CopyFiles();
        }
    }

    private void CopyFiles()
    {
        try
        { 
           InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
           File outfile = new File(DB_PATH,DB_NAME);
           outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
           outfile.createNewFile();

          if (is == null)
          throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
          else
          {
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);      
          // BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(outfile));
              byte buf[] = new byte[128];
                do {
              int numread = is.read(buf);
                    if (numread <= 0)
                        break;
              out.write(buf, 0, numread);
               } while (true);

                is.close();
                out.close();
          }
           //AssetFileDescriptor af = am.openFd("world_treasure_hunter_deluxe.apk");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
              throw new RuntimeException(e); 
        }

    }    

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        }

        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }



      /// Get Book content////////
      public Cursor getQuiz_Content(int bookId)     
      {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);       

        Cursor cur;
        cur=myData.rawQuery("select quiz_text from Quiz where quiz_id='"+bookId+"'",null);
        cur.moveToFirst();

        myData.close();
        return cur;
      };
      //////////////////////////



      /// Get Book content////////
      public Cursor getQuiz_List()     
      {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);       
        int i;

        Cursor cur;
        cur=myData.rawQuery("select quiz_id,quiz_text,correct_answer from quiz",null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        i = cur.getCount();
        myData.close();
        return cur;
      };
      //////////////////////////


      public Cursor getAns(int quizid)
      {
          String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
          myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

          Cursor cur;
          cur = myData.rawQuery("select answers from answer where quiz_id='"+quizid+"'", null);
          cur.moveToFirst();
          myData.close();
          return cur;
      }

      public Cursor getAnsList()
      {
          String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
          myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

          Cursor cur;
          cur = myData.rawQuery("select answers from answer", null);
          cur.moveToFirst();
          myData.close();

          return cur;  
      }



      //---updates a title---
     /* public boolean UpdateFavourite_Individual(long rowid,String fav) 
      {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

          ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
          args.put("bookmark", fav);
          return myData.update("lyrics", args, 
                           "rowid=" + rowid, null) > 0;                     
      }*/
      //////////////////


}
```

Here's Quiz.java:

```
    package com.myapps.quiz;

import java.io.IOException;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Quiz extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    final DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    Cursor c3;
    Cursor c4;
    int counter=1;  
    String label;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String options[] = new String[19];
     // get reference to radio group in layout
        RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
        // layout params to use when adding each radio button
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        c4 = db.getAnsList();
        c4.moveToFirst();
        for (int k=0;k<19;k++)
        {       
            options[k]=c4.getString(0);
            c4.moveToNext();
            Log.e("value:", options[k]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            final RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
            c3 = db.getAns(3);

        for (int j=0;j<i;j++)    
            c3.moveToNext();
           label = c3.getString(0);

        newRadioButton.setText(label);
        newRadioButton.setId(6);
        radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
        //getOptions();



        try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Cursor c1;

        c1= db.getQuiz_Content(counter);






        //rdoAns1.setText("Lisbon");

        final TextView tvQuizText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tvQuizText.setText(c1.getString(0));

        Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Cursor c2 = null ;
                    Cursor c3 =null;    

                    if (counter < 5)
                    {
                    counter +=1;    
                    c2 = db.getQuiz_Content(counter);
                    c3 = db.getAns(counter);
                    //Log.e("Row Position after increment:",Integer.toString(c2.getPosition()));
                    tvQuizText.setText(c2.getString(0));
                    }



                    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)    
                    {   
                        c3.moveToNext();
                       label = c3.getString(0);

                    newRadioButton.setText(label);

                    }

                    //Log.e("value:",Integer.toString(counter));
                    //Log.e("value",c3.getString(0));
            }
        });
        //c3 = db.getAns(4);
     // rdoAns1.setText(c3.getString(0));
      //rdoAns2.setText(c3.getString(1));
      //rdoAns3.setText(c3.getString(2));
      //rdoAns4.setText(c3.getString(3));
    }
    /** add radio buttons to the group */
   // private void getOptions()
    {

        // get reference to radio group in layout
        //RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
        // layout params to use when adding each radio button
        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
          //      RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            //    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // add 20 radio buttons to the group

        //for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
          //  RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
           // c3 = db.getAns(4);
        //for (int j=0;j<i;j++)    
          //  c3.moveToNext();
           // String label = c3.getString(0);

        //newRadioButton.setText(label);
        //newRadioButton.setId(i);
        //radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
        }

    }

    }
```

Here's my XML layout:

```
<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


                <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rdbGp1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_y="30dip"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                </RadioGroup>


<Button android:text="Save" android:id="@+id/btnSave" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="50dip" android:layout_y="250dip"></Button>
<Button android:text="Next" android:id="@+id/btnNext" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="175dip" android:layout_y="250dip"></Button>

<TextView android:layout_x="17dip" android:layout_y="15dip" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>






</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: It is very good to add the sample code to your question, but this is to much code. Which loop where? is the listener that reacts to the button pressed? Please post only the relevant code, not the complete app.

Comment: This is the code where the text is assigned to radiobuttons:
for (int j=0;j<3;j++)    
{   
     c3.moveToNext();
     label = c3.getString(0);

     newRadioButton.setText(label);

}

Comment: This loop is inside the button click listener.

Comment: @Maxood, can I get a copy of your Android quiz tutorial sample from your website? I have try to ask for it there but it doesn't accept my comment, my email is ignacioleon7@gmail.com thank you in advance.

Comment: @zvzej Sure! Please check your inbox and let me have your feedback.

Comment: @Maxood, got it will work with it, then will with you my feedback. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got this right, and the code is a little confusing with all those curly brackets, you create RadioButtons in for loop? You create newRadioButton and add it to layout. After that for finishes, you have newRadioButton that is the last one you created. And when you try to set text on NewRadioButton, the only thing you do is setting text on the same radio button 3 times.

So you have to get each RadioButton individually, using their RadioGroup.

I hope that helped.

Comment: I agree with you. I have 4 radio buttons whose text is being set in the following loop:
 for (int j=0;j<3;j++) { c3.moveToNext(); label = c3.getString(0); newRadioButton.setText(label); } 
The issue is that their names are the same ...right?Or is it something else? Please explain.

Comment: Their names are not the same, but you have one final variable newRadioButton and when you finish your first loop, the last RadioButton that you created will be newRadioButton. So when you go into the other loop, all you are doing is setting text 3 times on the same radio button.

The solution is to get each of your radio buttons from their parent radio group:  

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  c3.moveToNext();
  ((RadioButton)radiogroup.getChildAt(j)).setText(c3.getString(0));
}

Comment: Thanks i got my problem solved. Now i'm working on the scoring part of the quiz. For that i need to get the text of the selected radio button by the user.
How can i do that?

Comment: i can not check this now, but it should be ((RadioButton)radiogroup.findviewbyid(radiogroup.getcheckedradiobuttonid()).gettext()

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm done with the Quiz app and am going to post its tutorial on my blog:http://maxood-android-corner.blogspot.com/