# android viewFlipper, TextSwitcher or something else for quiz apps?

Tags: android, viewflipper

The first thing to say is im a beginner and now im developing my first "real" android apps(it will be on Google Play).
I already google a lot about this "Quiz" application for android and i cant get good information nor project examples about this one (most of the code/project examples is about a `viewFlipper`/`TextSwitcher` changing everytime you touch the screen --thats not what i want). I also tried to search in Stackoverflow and what i got is some downvoted question without a good/helping answer.

So there will be a quiz section in my app, and i will have  3 type of questions :

1. A question with a `radiobutton` answer
2. A question with a `checkboxlist` answer
3. A question with an `edittext` answer

There will be about 50 questions in my apps, so **i have a plan to create 3 different layouts**.

And these are my question's :

1. Do you have any links/examples?please share(I already try to find on my own) :D
2. What is the best way to do this?(Example : like using `viewFlipper` with layouts, or something else)
3. Is it possible to generate a 3 different types of question(3 layouts) using `viewFlipper`?how to do this?

Thank you :D

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060638/help-needed-for-android-quiz-app

Comment: Thanks for your help :D
I already check this one, but i cant understand it :(

Comment: Why Viewflipper? Do you want the user to swipe trough each question? Better take a button for "next question" :).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ahmad, i plan to make my apps could be swiped and also have a "next" button :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create one master layout for question, with a `TextView` for statement, a container (like `FrameLayout`) for answer layout , and next , previous `Button`'s.  In the container you can place two Views, a `ListView` and an `EditText` for editable answers. Visibility of both as GONE.

Now, Once you got master layout visible, you can load each question in same layout. You will need to set text of statement view, if your question has options, you set `ListView` visibile, load data in it and set it to single/multiple choice. Else, if you question has an editable answer, you set `EditText` visible, (set `ListView` visibilty to gone).

This will be much more efficient than inflating separate layouts per question, Also `ListView` perfectly handles any number of options , can be single/multiple choice and allows to scroll to any option independent of screen size.

Layout Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/question__Statement"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        <ListView android:id="@+id/question__options"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:visibility="gone"
                />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/question__text"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:visibility="gone"
                />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <Button android:id="@+id/question__prev"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Previous"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/question__next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Next"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D
Do you have any code example?it would be helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

I found a great sample app for you:

https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidChuckQuiz

It uses a SQLite database tough, you might want to read that up, before building an Application "on top" of that.